# Using Spy Object in PHPUnit?

Tags: php, phpunit, spy

How can I use Spy Object in PHPUnit?
You can call object in imitation on, and after you can assert how many times it called.
It is Spy.

I know "Mock" in PHPUnit as Stub Object and Mock Object.

Comment: What does *"You can call object in imitation on"* mean? *"how many times it called"*... you mean *"has been called"*?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can assert how many times a Mock was called with PHPUnit when doing

```
    $mock = $this->getMock('SomeClass');
    $mock->expects($this->exactly(5))
         ->method('someMethod')
         ->with(
             $this->equalTo('foo'), // arg1
             $this->equalTo('bar'), // arg2
             $this->equalTo('baz')  // arg3
         );
```

When you then call something in the TestSubject that invokes the Mock, PHPUnit will fail the test when SomeClass someMethod was not called five times with arguments foo,bar,baz. There is a number of [additional matchers besides `exactly`](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.4/en/test-doubles.html#test-doubles.mock-objects.tables.matchers).

In addition, [PHPUnit as has built-in support for using Prophecy](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/test-doubles.html#test-doubles.prophecy) to create test doubles since version 4.5. Please refer to the [documentation for Prophecy](https://github.com/phpspec/prophecy#how-to-use-it) for further details on how to create, configure, and use stubs, spies, and mocks using this alternative test double framework.

Comment: So I need to spend a week learnig a whole new whopping humongous framework just to be able to use The Full Power Of Code (rather than Extremely Poor Set Of Predefined Crap) to assert about arguments to a stubbed method?

Answer (score 7):

There's a spy returned from `$this->any()`, you can use it something like:

```
$foo->expects($spy = $this->any())->method('bar');
$foo->bar('baz');

$invocations = $spy->getInvocations();

$this->assertEquals(1, count($invocations));
$args = $invocations[0]->arguments;
$this->assertEquals(1, count($args));
$this->assertEquals('bar', $args[0]);
```

I put up a blog entry about this at some stage: http://blog.lyte.id.au/2014/03/01/spying-with-phpunit/

I have no idea where (if?) it's documented, I found it searching through PHPUnit code...

Comment: Is it just me or [is this no longer the case](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/60c32c5b5e79c2248001efa2560f831da11cc2d7/src/Framework/TestCase.php#L1898-L1901)?

Comment: As of 8.4.1, the tests fail as getInvocations() method no longer exists.
https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/issues/3888

Answer (score 0):

An update of @lyte's answers that works in 2018:

```
$foo->expects($spy = $this->any())->method('bar');
$foo->bar('baz');

$invocations = $spy->getInvocations();

$this->assertEquals(1, count($invocations));
$args = $invocations[0]->getParameters();
$this->assertEquals(1, count($args));
$this->assertEquals('bar', $args[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this :

```php
$mock = $this->getMock('SomeClass');
$mock->expects($spy = $this->any())
    ->method('someMethod')
    ->with(
        $this->equalTo('foo'), // arg1
        $this->equalTo('bar'), // arg2
        $this->equalTo('baz')  // arg3
    );
```

If you just want to check on call :

```php
self::assertTrue($spy->hasBeenInvoked());
```

If multiples :

```php
$this->assertEquals(5, count($spy->getInvocations()));
```